# Golangのhtml/templateでrangeの変数展開ができない

Tags: html, go

Golangのhtml/templateを使った下記のコードがうまく動きません。
template内でrangeを使い、struct a の rの要素を$index2で一つずつ展開させたいのですが、展開されず、Stdoutに何も表示されません。どうすれいいのでしょうか?

[このコードのPlayGround](http://play.golang.org/p/gmDFsYtq51)

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type a struct {
    r []string
}

func main() {
    my_struct := a{r:[]string{"A", "B", "C"}}
    template_string := "{{ range $index, $index2 := .r }} {{ $index2 }}{{ end }}"
    //range
    temp := template.Must(template.New("foo").Parse(template_string))
    temp.Execute(os.Stdout, my_struct)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp.Execute(os.Stdout, my_struct)
```

を、

```
if err := temp.Execute(os.Stdout, my_struct); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

として実行しますと、以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
template: foo:1:28: executing "foo" at <.r>: r is an unexported field of struct type main.a
```

つまり、フィールド `r` を `R` など(大文字で始まる名前)にする必要がありそうです。

実際、`R` に置き換えて実行しますと、

```
$ go run a.go
   A B C
```

となります。